# Change custom cell content view color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I added a change theme button in my main view controller where I have a tiny table view. I can change every color except a table view cell's Content View background color, and I can't access it outside cellForRowAt.

What should I do? Is there anyway to trigger a function from my custom Cell to change the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing `delegate`, if you have custom cell class and access the delegate method to change content view color.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property in your controller to determine the color of the cells. When you wanna change the color, you call `tableView.reloadData()`. This will make `cellForRowAt` be called on each visible cell, and you can change color in this delegate method.

`Your viewController`

```
YourViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate var cellColor = UIColor.blue

    // where you change color
    func changeColor() {
        cellColor = UIColor.red
        // this will make the delegate method `cellForRowAt` be called on each visible row
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

`cellForRowAt:`

```
// delegate method
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuse id", for: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = cellColor
    // anything else...
    return cell
}
```